# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' to 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

```cs
public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public AuthContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {}
}
```

In the above code snippet : options sent as parameter to base keyword is giving the same error :

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' to 'string'

Comment: Could you provide the error message? How do you inject DbContext in Startup.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IdentityDbContext` constructor is expecting an argument from type `string`. You are passing it a type `DbContextOptions` so you're getting that error.

The string you probably want to pass is the name of the relevant connection string which is located in the web config file.

For example:

```
// web config file

<connectionStrings>
   <add name="AuthContextName" connectionString="your-connection-string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

// your AuthContext class

public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext
{
   public AuthContext(DbContextOptions options) : base("AuthContextName")
   {}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look into this Ran , I am really not sure why the instructor i was following made same code snippet and was working fine for him .

Comment: Thanks Ryan , Your comment made e think in that direction . Actually there was no method in base class accepting 1 DbContextOptions parameter . As you said ,  I was using a wrong namespace . using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;  instead of this core name space I was using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework .

Comment: You're much welcome my friend

Answer (score 1):

You may be calling from the wrong library.

Be sure that using this library: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext